# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method or property

Tags: blazor

Trying to figure out the best way to do basic math with blazor.  I want to enter a number, display that number (currentValue), and then display that number doubled (newValue). But I can't figure out how to reference the first number.

```
@page "/Double"

<h3>Double</h3>

<p>
    <input @bind="currentValue" /> @currentValue <br />
    Value doubled: @newValue
</p>

@code {
    public string currentValue;
    public int newValue = Convert.ToDouble(currentValue) * 2;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blazor, but do you need getters and setters on your properties? E.g. public string currentValue {get;set;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `=` to `=>` and use a `double`

```
@page "/Double"

<h3>Double</h3>

<p>
    <input @bind="currentValue" /> @currentValue <br />
    Value doubled: @newValue
</p>

@code {
    public string currentValue;
    public double newValue => Convert.ToDouble(currentValue) * 2;
}
```

Comment: Note that newValue is now no longer a field but a read-only property. The preferred name is NewValue.